# HP 5200tn installation error with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 5200tn printer. I successfully installed it using USB port and ran smoothly. I tried to use it as a network printer, plugged it to an Ethernet switch with one PC to examine the network installation. I manually adjusted the network settings for both the printer and the PC. For the printer:

```
IP Address  192.168.10.254
Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.10.254
```

And for the PC (Windows XP, Service Pack 3):

```
IP Address  192.168.10.116
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.10.254
```

Installing from the CD, I've chosen the basic installation as suggested. After a while I got an error:

> Setup has encountered a severe error and will now exit. Restart your
>   computer and run setup again.

And then rolls back and exit. So I did restrart and tried again several times, all with the same result. I tried the full installation and the custom installation, all resulted in the same error. Tried to google up the error but I couldn't find something useful. Is my configuration OK? Am I on the right path for setting a network printer (since I haven't done that before)? and what's going wrong? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Get the latest software/driver from HP....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=1137924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [HP Install Network Printer Wizard](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=19656&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=27908).

It simplified the process and actually got it done. I still needed the driver from the CD.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, both your PC and printer have IP's on the same local subnet (192.168.10.*) and mask. But you should not use 192.168.10.254 for anything, change the printer to something else (like 192.168.10.150). The gateway setting you would normally have as the address of your router (if it's connected via ethernet and is on the same subnet).

As your software installation doesn't seem to have worked i would doublecheck the printer is configured by launching `Command Prompt` on your PC and 'pinging' the printer by typing `ping 192.168.10.150`.

You will hopefully find with changing the printer from 192.168.10.254 that the installation is then able to continue. I'll let someone else explain why 192.168.10.254 shouldn't be used (it's to do with network devices broadcasting).

Comment: +1 , though don't have enough reputation here to actually upvote :)and thank you. Yes I know about the broadcasting address, I just didn't take that into consideration and used whatever..

Comment: So is your problem resolved? The IP address change solved the setup error message?

Comment: No it didn't by that.. It is a software problem I guess. I think there is some software missing in the CD and I downloaded a software from HP.. I'll add an answer...

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted :)